# li is not being filled up by anchor tag

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am trying to create a navigation menu for wordpress. Somehow the first anchor tag is able to take the whole list item for the title but for the archives, I have rotated the anchor tag but whether I rotate the anchor tag or not, it refuses to take up the whole list item as clickable link. What am I missing and how do I go around solving this? Thanks in advance.

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zfp3/

```
<header class="navbar">
  <nav class="menu-item-container">
    <ul class="navblog">
        <li class="brand">
          <a href="#" class="brand">title</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-106" class="navlinks archives menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106">
          <a href="http://localhost/wp/archives/">Archives</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar navsocial">
        <li>
          <a href="//facebook.com" class="navlinks navsocial facebook"><span class="icon-facebook facebook icon-large "></span>facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="//twitter.com/" class="navlinks navsocial twitter"><span class="icon-twitter icon-large "></span>twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="//twitch.tv//" class="navlinks navsocial twitchtv"><span class="icon-youtube-play icon-large "></span>twitch.tv</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="//ggtracker.com" class="navlinks navsocial ggtracker"><span class="icon-gamepad icon-large"></span>ggtracker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="//ggtracker.com" class="navlinks navsocial ggtracker"><span class="icon-gamepad icon-large"></span>ggtracker</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a, li, span, p, input, html, body {
    font-family:"Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    &:visited {
        color: #fff;
    }

}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.pull-right {
    float:right;
}

.pull-left {
    float:left;
}

::selection {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(242, 56, 90, 0.2);
}

::-moz-selection {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(242, 56, 90, 0.2);
}

/* line 5, scss/header.scss */
li > a {
    display: block;
}

/* line 9, scss/header.scss */
nav.menu-item-container {
    font-size: 6rem;
    max-height: 160px;
}

/* line 14, scss/header.scss */
.navbar.navsocial, nav.menu-item-container, .navblog {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    display: flexbox;
}

/* line 20, scss/header.scss */
.navbar.navsocial {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 160px;
    max-width: 19%;
}

/* line 26, scss/header.scss */
.navbar.navsocial > li > a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 32px;
}

/* line 33, scss/header.scss */
.navblog {
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    width: 81%;
}

/* line 39, scss/header.scss */
li.brand {
    flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
}

/* line 43, scss/header.scss */
li.brand > a {
    height: 160px;
}

/* line 48, scss/header.scss */
li.archives {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

/* line 53, scss/header.scss */
li.archives > a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}

/* line 60, scss/header.scss */
li.archives > a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f099";
}

/* line 66, scss/header.scss */
a.facebook {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* line 70, scss/header.scss */
a.twitter {
    background-color: orange;
}

/* line 74, scss/header.scss */
a.ggtracker {
    background-color: purple;
}

/* line 78, scss/header.scss */
a.twitchtv {
    background-color: green;
}

/* line 82, scss/header.scss */
a.brand {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Put `display:block` to your `a` style.

Comment: I didn't want it to be so general that all anchor tags must be display:block. I added the style into the li.archives > a class but it won't make the whole li clickable. You could take a look at the JSFiddle and adding display: block to a does not work.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Maybe this helps you: `li.archives > a { height: 80px; line-height: 80px }`

Comment: if you take a look at the fiddle, you would see that every other li is a clickable li whereas the archives li isn't. Only the anchor tag is clickable which doesn't take up the whole li even after adding display: block. I would like to know why that is happening and how to rectify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird that the anchor isn't taking up the whole li. I tried removing some of the styles to see if it conflicts, but it doesn't make a difference.

Anyways, I just played around with the dimensions of the li and anchor, and it seems to work [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zfp3/1/)

```
/* line 48, scss/header.scss */
li.archives {
  width: 161px;
  background-color: red;
}

/* line 53, scss/header.scss */
li.archives > a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
    width: 159px;
    height: 159px;
}
```

Unfortunately it's fixed dimensions and not percentage based, it doesn't seem to want to take percentages either.

Maybe recreate the li without those menu-item id's and classes and see if it works.